# Can't roll backing paper on printing from Winforms C# Application .Using TVS 245 Star

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

Iam using tvs 245 star for printing from my c# winforms application (Crystal report is used for printing).I want to print a bill of supermarket.Now its printing and rolling to top for cut the paper .I want to print the next bill by rolling back the paper.Is there any way to roll back the paper from C# winform application ?